# Getting Error while using sections and tableviewcells together while working with SFRestAPI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures

```
var accountId = String()
var dataRows = [NSDictionary]()
var grandChilds = [NSDictionary]()
var dataOfGrandChilds = NSMutableDictionary()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("loaded hie \(accountId)")
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT Name,Id FROM Account where parentid='\(self.accountId)'");
    //SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { responce in print(responce)
        self.dataRows = responce["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
        var counter = 0;
        for i in self.dataRows
        {
            let requestForGrandChilds = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select Name,Id from Account where parentid='\(i["Id"]!)'")
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
            failBlock:
            {
                error in print(error)
                print("error block")
            },
            completeBlock:
            {
                responceChild in
                self.grandChilds = responceChild["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
                self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"] = self.grandChilds
                print(self.dataOfGrandChilds)
                counter += 1
                print("control still in inner competion block")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    { () -> Void in
                        print("Control came to main queue")
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })   
        }

    })

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if(dataOfGrandChilds.count > 0 ){
        return dataOfGrandChilds.count
    }
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return dataRows[section]["Name"] as? String
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toViewChilds", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print(indexPath.section)
    print(dataOfGrandChilds["\(indexPath.section)"])
    if let tempData = dataOfGrandChilds["\(indexPath.section)"]
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String
    }
    return cell
}
```

In the first request I'm trying fetch direct child accounts of an Id. In the completion block of 1st request I'm trying to fetch grand child accounts . 
    dataRows is having data for section headers ( Which are direct child names).
    dataOfGrandChilds is dictionary that is holding section number as key and corresponding grandChilds array as its value.

[image]

On reloading my tableView I'm able to display only 1st sections child but not second sections child. Please help finding solution.

The error that i'm getting is

> 2016-06-07 11:10:30.764 iCRM[67964:11218133] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  You have tried to access the second element of an array that contains only 1 element

Comment: cell.textLabel?.text = tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String
@Paulw11
In this line it is getting crashed.

Comment: Right, so you are accessing your `tempData` array which is based on an entry in the `dataOfGrandchilds[section]`, but `numberOfRowsInSection` does not return a value based on the same data. It returns 1 or the number of sections.

Comment: So how do I overcome this problem @Paulw11

Comment: You should return the correct value from `numberOfRowsInSection` ie. `dataOfGrandChilds[section].count`

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11
that has to be done and also i checked for nil using optional binding. Now I've managed to get it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var accountId = String()
var dataRows = [NSDictionary]()
var grandChilds = [NSDictionary]()
var dataOfGrandChilds = NSMutableDictionary()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("loaded hie \(accountId)")
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT Name,Id FROM Account where parentid='\(self.accountId)'");
    //SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { responce in print(responce)
        self.dataRows = responce["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
        var counter = 0;
        for i in self.dataRows
        {
            let requestForGrandChilds = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select Name,Id from Account where parentid='\(i["Id"]!)'")
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
            failBlock:
            {
                error in print(error)
                print("error block")
            },
            completeBlock:
            {
                responceChild in
                self.grandChilds = responceChild["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
                self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"] = self.grandChilds
                print(self.dataOfGrandChilds)
                counter += 1
                print("control still in inner competion block")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    { () -> Void in
                        print("Control came to main queue")
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })   
        }

    })

}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if let countOfRows = dataOfGrandChilds[section]?.count  // to avoid un-wrapping nil value
    {
        return countOfRows
    }
    return 1
}





override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return dataRows[section]["Name"] as? String
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toViewChilds", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print(indexPath.section)
    print(dataOfGrandChilds["\(indexPath.section)"])
   if let tempData = dataOfGrandChilds["\(indexPath.section)"]
    {
        if(tempData.count != 0 )//to avoid array index out of bound exceptions
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Changes done are :

1. numberOfRowsInSection(): 
         returned correct number of rows
2. cellForRowAtIndexPath():
         tempData.count != 0 as we need to avoid NSRangeException